# NTriples loading all the data inside Annotation Properties in Protege?

Tags: semantic-web, ontology, protege, n-triples

This is my little portion of NTriples:

```
<myOnt#hasRanking> <rdfs-ns#type> <owl#ObjectProperty> .
<myOnt#hasRanking> <rdfs#range> <myOnt#Ranking> .
<myOnt#hasRanking> <rdfs#domain> <myOnt#Faculty> .
```

The full code can be seen as:

> https://pastebin.com/wRfyns2b

But the Problem is, protege, instead of defining the appropriate classes and their relations what it goes is this (puts everything inside Annotation Properties":

[image: Example]

How can I represent it in its proper form?

Answer (score 2):

If the property declarations are missing, the input is invalid for Protégé. In that situation, Protégé considers the undeclared properties as annotation properties and parses the input accordingly. To fix it, you need to declare the properties as data or object properties, or add an import to an ontology that includes the necessary declarations.

From looking at the complete file, I think the problem is that you're attempting to use shortened namespaces for the `type` property. Use absolute IRIs or use a format that supports namespace shortening.